# DynamoDB's PutItem is multiple zones safe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Accoring  to the link [1]

```
 Amazon DynamoDB has built-in fault tolerance, automatically and synchronously
 replicating your data across three Availability Zones in a Region for high 
 availability and to help protect your data against individual machine, or even
 facility failures.
```

So can I assume that, at the time I get result for a success write, it is already replicated into three Availability zones?

[1] http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on how you do the read:

from http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/

Q: What is the consistency model of Amazon DynamoDB?
When reading data from Amazon DynamoDB, users can specify whether they want the read to be eventually consistent or strongly consistent:

*Eventually Consistent Reads* (Default) – **the eventual consistency option maximizes your read throughput. However, an eventually consistent read might not reflect the results of a recently completed write.** Consistency across all copies of data is usually reached within a second. Repeating a read after a short time should return the updated data.

*Strongly Consistent Reads* — in addition to eventual consistency, **Amazon DynamoDB also gives you the flexibility and control to request a strongly consistent read if your application, or an element of your application, requires it. A strongly consistent read returns a result that reflects all writes that received a successful response prior to the read.**

Comment: It is irrelevant to how I read. Consider at the moment after the PutItem API, if the machine failed completely, will it lead to data loss? Or AWS will make sure the PutItem is replicated to several machine in the same zone before return the success. You can see no read is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rely on the data being there if `PutItem` succeeded.

> automatically and synchronously replicating your data across three Availability Zones

The keyword is *synchronously*, meaning at the same time.  At the same time it accepts your data, it's writing to all three Availability Zones.  If `PutItem` returned before copmleting those writes, DynamoDB wouldn't have the consistency and durability guarantees advertised.